# Using JavaScript. Need to find the Vertex and Axis of Symmetry

Tags: javascript, html, quadratic

Creating a code using JS that can solve and graph quadratics. The parts I'm having an issue with would be finding and reducing axis of symmetry and vertex.
I've attempted to do the Axis of Symm but it does not work. The html code is for the box i would like the Axis of Symm to show up in. Thanks all!

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a>Axis of Symmetry</a></br>
            <input id="Axis" type="text" readonly="readonly"></input>
            </br>
            <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="cancel()"></input>
    </td>
</tr>

<script>
//Axis of Symmetry//
var AOS= ((-b) / (2*a));
document.getElementById('Axis').value = AOS;
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to show your attempts so far so that we know where you are getting stuck. Would you mind editing your question to show what you have done so far? It would also be much better to break this question up into multiple questions (for example, only ask about the axis of symmetry problem part here and then open another question about the other parts). But first, it is most important to show that you’ve put in time to try to solve this problem.

Comment: Advice taken! I added the code I've got so far.

Comment: you should also only include the code that is relevant here (the JavaScript part). You might find [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) helpful. The Stack Overflow community has a specific way to ask questions and it ends up being very beneficial to know how to ask/format your questions so that we can help get you a good answer.

Comment: I put a relevant snippet of the code up now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Incorrect Code to Fix

First of all, the `<input>` tag does not have a closing tag (you shouldn't have `</input>` - it doesn't exist). Secondly, when you want to break a line, you use the `<br />` tag. `</br>` is not a valid tag.

## Working with Javascript `onclick`

It looks like you would be best off making a function (I call it `calculate` below) to get the values for your quadratic equation and then display the result for the axis of symmetry. See the Javascript code below to see how I would implement this.

## A Solution

Below is a working example on how to calculate the axis of symmetry. I've made a functional [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jackmoody11/aw2xzypk/1/) if you would like to see this code in action.

**HTML**

```html
<p>
    Please provide real constants a, b, and c in the boxes 
    below corresponding to the quadratic equation a*x^2 + b*x + c
</p>

<span style="display:inline-block">
    <label for="a" style="display:block;">a</label>
    <input type="number" name="a" id="a" />
</span>

<span style="display:inline-block">
    <label for="b"  style="display:block;">b</label>
    <input type="number" name="b" id="b"/>
</span>

<span style="display:inline-block">
    <label for="c"  style="display:block;">c</label>
    <input type="number" name="c" id="c" />
</span>

<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()">
<br />
<br />

<tr>
    <td>
        <a>Axis of Symmetry</a><br />
            <input id="Axis" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="">
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="cancel()">
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Javascript** (*put this in between `<style>` and `</style>`*):

```js
// Calculate axis of symmetry
function calculate(){
    var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
    var c = document.getElementById('c').value;

    if(isNaN(a) || isNaN(b) || isNaN(c)){
        window.alert("Please enter valid numbers for a, b, and c.");
    }
    else{
      var AOS= ((-b) / (2*a));
      document.getElementById('Axis').value = AOS;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a bunch!